# Exponential backoff average number of collisions

Tags: algorithm, networking, exponential

I'm working on a simple exponential backoff algorithm and I'm wondering if my results are correct. Here are the assumptions:

- There are N stations
- Each station has 1 packet to send
- Initially, all stations try to send in time slot 0
- A collision occurs when two or more stations want to send their frame in the same time slot (thus all stations' frames collide during the first round)
- When a collision occurs, the station calculates its waiting time using the exponential backoff function (that is, after c collisions, it will wait a random number of time slots from 0 to 2^c - 1)

I coded in Java. Here are the results for a run using 10 stations:

```
Slot 0:  Station 0 Station 1 Station 2 Station 3 Station 4 Station 5 Station 6 Station 7 Station 8 Station 9 
Slot 1:  
Slot 2:  
Slot 3:  
Slot 4:  
Slot 5:  
Slot 6:  
Slot 7:  
Slot 8:  
Slot 9:  
Slot 10:     
Slot 11:     
Slot 12:     
Slot 13:     
Slot 14:     
Slot 15:     
Slot 16:     
Slot 17:     
Slot 18:     
Slot 19:     
Slot 20:     
Slot 21:     
Slot 22:     
Slot 23:     
Slot 24:     
Slot 25:     
Slot 26:     
Slot 27:     
Slot 28:     
Slot 29:     
Slot 30:     
Slot 31:     
Slot 32:     
Slot 33:     
Slot 34:     
Slot 35:     
Slot 36:     
Slot 37:     
Slot 38:     
Slot 39:     
Slot 40:     
Slot 41:     
Slot 42:     
Slot 43:     
Slot 44:     
Slot 45:     
Slot 46:     
Slot 47:     
Slot 48:     
Slot 49:     
Collisions in round 1: Station 0 Station 1 Station 2 Station 3 Station 4 Station 5 Station 6 Station 7 Station 8 Station 9 
Slot 0:  
Slot 1:  Station 1 Station 3 Station 5 Station 6 
Slot 2:  Station 0 Station 2 Station 4 Station 7 Station 8 Station 9 
Slot 3:  
Slot 4:  
Slot 5:  
Slot 6:  
Slot 7:  
Slot 8:  
Slot 9:  
Slot 10:     
Slot 11:     
Slot 12:     
Slot 13:     
Slot 14:     
Slot 15:     
Slot 16:     
Slot 17:     
Slot 18:     
Slot 19:     
Slot 20:     
Slot 21:     
Slot 22:     
Slot 23:     
Slot 24:     
Slot 25:     
Slot 26:     
Slot 27:     
Slot 28:     
Slot 29:     
Slot 30:     
Slot 31:     
Slot 32:     
Slot 33:     
Slot 34:     
Slot 35:     
Slot 36:     
Slot 37:     
Slot 38:     
Slot 39:     
Slot 40:     
Slot 41:     
Slot 42:     
Slot 43:     
Slot 44:     
Slot 45:     
Slot 46:     
Slot 47:     
Slot 48:     
Slot 49:     
Collisions in round 2: Station 0 Station 1 Station 2 Station 3 Station 4 Station 5 Station 6 Station 7 Station 8 Station 9 
Slot 0:  
Slot 1:  
Slot 2:  Station 3 
Slot 3:  Station 0 Station 2 Station 4 Station 6 
Slot 4:  Station 1 Station 8 Station 9 
Slot 5:  Station 5 Station 7 
Slot 6:  
Slot 7:  
Slot 8:  
Slot 9:  
Slot 10:     
Slot 11:     
Slot 12:     
Slot 13:     
Slot 14:     
Slot 15:     
Slot 16:     
Slot 17:     
Slot 18:     
Slot 19:     
Slot 20:     
Slot 21:     
Slot 22:     
Slot 23:     
Slot 24:     
Slot 25:     
Slot 26:     
Slot 27:     
Slot 28:     
Slot 29:     
Slot 30:     
Slot 31:     
Slot 32:     
Slot 33:     
Slot 34:     
Slot 35:     
Slot 36:     
Slot 37:     
Slot 38:     
Slot 39:     
Slot 40:     
Slot 41:     
Slot 42:     
Slot 43:     
Slot 44:     
Slot 45:     
Slot 46:     
Slot 47:     
Slot 48:     
Slot 49:     
Collisions in round 3: Station 0 Station 1 Station 2 Station 4 Station 5 Station 6 Station 7 Station 8 Station 9 
Slot 0:  
Slot 1:  
Slot 2:  Station 3 
Slot 3:  
Slot 4:  
Slot 5:  Station 6 
Slot 6:  
Slot 7:  Station 9 
Slot 8:  Station 0 
Slot 9:  Station 1 Station 4 
Slot 10:     Station 8 
Slot 11:     Station 2 
Slot 12:     Station 7 
Slot 13:     Station 5 
Slot 14:     
Slot 15:     
Slot 16:     
Slot 17:     
Slot 18:     
Slot 19:     
Slot 20:     
Slot 21:     
Slot 22:     
Slot 23:     
Slot 24:     
Slot 25:     
Slot 26:     
Slot 27:     
Slot 28:     
Slot 29:     
Slot 30:     
Slot 31:     
Slot 32:     
Slot 33:     
Slot 34:     
Slot 35:     
Slot 36:     
Slot 37:     
Slot 38:     
Slot 39:     
Slot 40:     
Slot 41:     
Slot 42:     
Slot 43:     
Slot 44:     
Slot 45:     
Slot 46:     
Slot 47:     
Slot 48:     
Slot 49:     
Collisions in round 4: Station 1 Station 4 
Slot 0:  
Slot 1:  
Slot 2:  Station 3 
Slot 3:  
Slot 4:  
Slot 5:  Station 6 
Slot 6:  
Slot 7:  Station 9 
Slot 8:  Station 0 
Slot 9:  
Slot 10:     Station 8 
Slot 11:     Station 2 
Slot 12:     Station 7 
Slot 13:     Station 5 
Slot 14:     Station 1 
Slot 15:     
Slot 16:     
Slot 17:     
Slot 18:     
Slot 19:     
Slot 20:     
Slot 21:     
Slot 22:     
Slot 23:     Station 4 
Slot 24:     
Slot 25:     
Slot 26:     
Slot 27:     
Slot 28:     
Slot 29:     
Slot 30:     
Slot 31:     
Slot 32:     
Slot 33:     
Slot 34:     
Slot 35:     
Slot 36:     
Slot 37:     
Slot 38:     
Slot 39:     
Slot 40:     
Slot 41:     
Slot 42:     
Slot 43:     
Slot 44:     
Slot 45:     
Slot 46:     
Slot 47:     
Slot 48:     
Slot 49:     
Collisions in round 5: No collisions!
Total number of collisions: 77
Station 0 sent at time slot 8 with 3 collisions.
Station 1 sent at time slot 14 with 4 collisions.
Station 2 sent at time slot 11 with 3 collisions.
Station 3 sent at time slot 2 with 2 collisions.
Station 4 sent at time slot 23 with 4 collisions.
Station 5 sent at time slot 13 with 3 collisions.
Station 6 sent at time slot 5 with 3 collisions.
Station 7 sent at time slot 12 with 3 collisions.
Station 8 sent at time slot 10 with 3 collisions.
Station 9 sent at time slot 7 with 3 collisions.
```

Does this look right? I can't seem to find anywhere what the average number of collisions should be for N stations using this function, so I'm not sure if I've messed anything up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the total number of collisions 83?

Comment: How can Station 2 have sent at time slot 0 if it had collisions? You need to explain your output a little better, because it doesn't make much sense. Also, a look at your code would probably give us a better idea of whether your implementation of the algorithm is correct.

Comment: @JimMischel Station 2 would have chosen to wait 0 time slots after 1 collision and 0 time slots after 2 collisions, right? Unless I'm misunderstanding the function altogether.

Comment: I don't know what Station 2 did. Your explanation seems reasonable. You might get more information if you logged all activity at each time period.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that a station can try to send multiple times in a single time slot. Seems to me that the backoff value should be the number of time slots that the station *skips*. So if station A gets a collision at time period 1 and elects to skip 0 time slots, it will be scheduled to send again at time slot 2. It won't try to re-send during the same time slot.

That makes a lot more sense. A station can attempt at most one send during a time slot.

So if everybody tries to send at time slot 0, they will all get a collision and elect to skip a random number of time slots from 0 to 2^i-1 (where i is the current time slot). Because 2^i-1 is 0, they'll all try to send at time slot 1.

*On average*, half of them will try to send during time slot 2 and half will try to send during time slot 3. Assume that the odd-numbered stations elected not to skip, and the even-numbered stations all skipped one slot. At the end of time slot 1, your state looks like this:

```
slot    stations
 2      1, 3, 5, 7, 9
 3      2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

There will be collisions during time slot 2, as well. The stations will each elect to skip 0, 1, 2, or 3 time slots. After time slot 2, your state would be something like:

```
slot    stations
 3      1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
 4      3, 7
 5      9
 6      5
```

Due to collisions in time slot 3, those six stations will spread themselves out among time slots 4 through 10 (electing to skip from 0 to 7 time slots). I'll let you build the corresponding state.

Eventually you'll get to a point where there is a single station at the current time slot, and that station can then send.

If you think about the problem this way, it becomes much easier to debug your code because you can build a table and show the state at the end of each time period. That will tell you if you're correctly picking the backoff values and if you're scheduling the stations correctly based on the selected backoff values.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edited my original question with the new output (apologies for the roughness, it shows all slots at every round). It appears to be working correctly...?